# Wordpress Blogname not changing even though set correctly in database

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with my wordpress site. When I was doing the development locally on my computer, I called the blog **DivoBlog** but when I hosted it online, I changed the name to **DivoSays**. When I visit this blog page http://divosays.com/blog/ of the website. The title is **DIVOBLOG BLOG**. I was expecting **DIVOSAYS BLOG**. Why is DIVOBLOG still appearing? In my wp_options table, the blogname is DivoSays. I am using the hueman theme.

Comment: Try overriding it as in this example here :  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99746/defined-blogname-override

Comment: Hi @SamuelJackson. That soln doesn't work. I can successfully edit my site title.